# Adding Node to Initially Null LinkedList

Tags: java, algorithm, list, recursion, null

I'm having issues when I try to add a node to a linked list that is initialized to null. In my method I set a test case to check if the node is initially null and if so it creates a new node with the value that was passed in. But for whatever reason it doesn't work unless the node has atleast one element already passed in. Check it out:

```
    Node addNode(Node node, int val)
    {
        if(node == null)
            {
                Node newNode = new Node(val);
                //node = newNode;
                return newNode;
            }
        node.next = addNode(node.next, val);
        return node;
    }

//Driver Class
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Node myNode = new Node(1);
    int numEntries = in.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numEntries ; i++)
    {
        int inputVal = in.nextInt();
        myNode.addNode(myNode, inputVal);
    }
```

The above code will not run if myNode is initialized to a null value (Node myNode = null;)

Full Code:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

   import java.util.*;
   import java.lang.*;
   import java.io.*;




/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
    class Ideone
    {
     public static class Node
     {
         private int value;
         Node next;
         public Node()
         {
             next = null;
         }
         public Node(int val)
         {
            value = val;
            next = null;
        }
        Node addNode(Node node, int val)
        {
            if(node == null)
                {
                    Node newNode = new Node(val);
                    //node = newNode;
                    return newNode;
                }
            node.next = addNode(node.next, val);
            return node;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Node myNode = new Node(1);
        Node current = null;
        Node oddFirst = new Node(1);
        int numEntries = in.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < numEntries ; i++)
        {
            int inputVal = in.nextInt();
            myNode.addNode(myNode, inputVal);
        }
        current = myNode;
        while(current != null) // Check if values were copied correctly
        {
            if(oddFirst == null) 
            {
                oddFirst = new Node(current.value);
            }
            oddFirst.addNode(oddFirst,current.value);
            //oddFirst = current.next;
            //oddFirst = oddFirst.next;
            current = current.next.next;
        }
        while(oddFirst != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Current Value: " + oddFirst.value);
            oddFirst = oddFirst.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to initialize `myNode` to null, and then call `myNode.addNode()` on it in the for loop?

Comment: @gla3dr yes thats what I'm saying.

Comment: Why not use java.util.LinkedList? and simply do list.add(new Node(inputVal));

Do you have a special need that doesn't allow an already existing linked list implementation from the standard lib?

Comment: @reegnz I'm practicing for an interview so I should know how to implement a linked list from scratch

Comment: Then look at java.util.LinkedList source":
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/935758609767/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java

Comment: Well, first of all you can't call a method like `addNode` on null.

Comment: @gla3dr how do I adjust it? I tried to make it a void method

Comment: If node is null, the method will fail with a NullPointerException when calling addNode. If it is not null, then the other branch will happen.
basically, the null check should be outside the addNode method and
you need to keep track of the end of the list explicitly.

Comment: Is it a requirement to solve this with recursion?

Comment: @reegnz nah its not but thats just the way I know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution for a linked list:

```
class Node {
    int val;
    Node next;
}

public class LinkedList {
    public Node first;
    public Node last;
    public void addNext(int val) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.val = val;
        if(last == null) {
            first = last = node;
        }
        else {
            last.next = node;
            last = node;
        }
    }
}
```

The main issue with the original code is that it doesn't concern itself with the case of the empty list.
You cannot discern the case where the list is comprised of a single 1 value, and the empty list.

Comment: @MannyO Actually the solution is a simplified version of the java.util.LinkedList solution. You should really read the code for that.
Programming is mainly about reading source code, not writing it.

Comment: yea I think ill read the source code and try get a better understanding of it. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not handling the return value of addNode().

You're returning a Node in the following function:

```
Node addNode(Node node, int val)
```

but you're not handling the return here:

```
myNode.addNode(myNode, inputVal);
```

This should help you figure out the solution.

Comment: Hmmm, How do you mean?

Comment: Look at the addNode(). you're returning a "Node". Where are you handling that return value??

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. The main issue is the null value. Even if you handle the return value, you have to start out with something in his solution.

Comment: try myNode = myNode.addNode(myNode, inputVal);

Comment: myNode = myNode.addNode(myNode, inputVal); didn't work

Comment: I tried the same case in C++ before and I thought it had something to do with pointers and memory

Comment: The issue is he doesn't know what the initial value of myNode should be. If it is null, your addNode call will fail with a NullPointerException.

Comment: @reegnz but I have the case in case the node is null